# How to autogenerate name using first name and last name using quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Here i have 2 names, firstname & lastname. How do i autogenerate a different name using first and last names
 (eg: firstname.lastname or  firstname_lastname)

```
<q-input name="firstname" v-model="first" float-label="First name"
 v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" clearable/>
            <i v-show="errors.has('firstname')" class="fa fa-warning "></i>
            <div class="containerError">   
               <span v-show="errors.has('firstname')" class="text-negative text-right">{{ errors.first('firstname') }}</span>
            </div>

<q-input name="lastname" required="required" v-model="last" float-label="Last name" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" clearable />
            <i v-show="errors.has('lasttname')" class="fa fa-warning "></i>
            <div class="containerError">    <span v-show="errors.has('lastname')" class="text-negative text-right">{{ errors.first('lastname') }}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: I't's not clear what your'e asking, do you want to add a new property to the model? do you want to just display the full name?

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
            <div v-if="this.last != ''"  float-label="fullname">
            User-name :{ {this.first}}.{{this.last}}  
            </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.